# RSpec Capybara::ElementNotFound Ajax field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

On page load I have

```
<table id="identity">
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tfooter>...</tfooter>
</table>
```

There is an ajax request that fires on page load, gathers data and then fills in the table.

I want to test content from within the  that is added to the table.

I have:

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 30
page.find("#identity tbody").should have_content "TEST CONTENT"
```

This is returning the error:

```
Failure/Error: page.find("#identity tbody").should have_content "TEST CONTENT"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "#identity tbody"
```

The test is running in under the default_wait_time so its clearly not waiting for the element. Is there anything I am missing with default_wait_time ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#finding

It should be something like this:

```
find("#identity").find("tbody").should have_content "TEST CONTENT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this,

```
 Capybara.page.find("#identity").should have_content "TEST CONTENT"
```

When there is a problem in syntax it doesn't wait given in default time.